# Getting the result of this SQL query in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sql

[I have a table containing the columns for employee name, date, and how late they are that date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3436G.png)

I want to fill a cell with the content of the column 'Late By' using the criteria 'Employee Name' and 'Date'. How can I get the result of this query using only Excel formulae?

`SELECT 'Late By' FROM 'augustAttendance' WHERE 'Employee Name'='Lauren Ipsum' AND 'date'='augustAttendance[Date]'`

Comment: Where you've the table? In Excel already? Please post sample data with desired output

Comment: Do you want to transform the SQL to Excel formula?

Comment: You use single quote chars for both string literals and column names which is obviously ambiguous. Check Help for correct syntax.